# Conditional Panel based on number of user selected inputs

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny

I am trying to get a different number of fields to populate based on the number of entries selected in a selectInput with multiple = TRUE.  So if 1 entry from the "numfields" input is selected, the first conditionalPanel appears, and so on. What I have now shows the inputs I want to be conditional without any user input.

```
  a <- c("A","B","C")

  Choices <- as.character(a)

  ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      selectInput(inputId = "numfields", label = "Select Entries", choices = Choices, multiple = TRUE, selectize = TRUE),
      conditionalPanel(
          condition = "count(input$numfields) >= 1",
          textInput(inputId = "field1", label = "First One", value = "")
        ),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "count(input$numfields) >= 2",
        textInput(inputId = "field2", label = "Second One", value = "")
      ),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "count(input$numfields) >= 3",
        textInput(inputId = "field3", label = "Third One", value = "")
      )
      )
    )

  server <- function(input, output, session)
  {}

  shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Also, on a related note, Shiny automatically defaults to have no entries selected for selectInput fields where multiple = TRUE.  Is there a way to have it select the first entry like it does when multiple = FALSE?

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here another solution via the server.
The obvious solution would be `renderUI()`, but if you want to use `condtionalPanel()`:

```
a <- c("A","B","C")

Choices <- as.character(a)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    selectInput(inputId = "numfields", label = "Select Entries", choices = Choices, multiple = TRUE, selectize = TRUE),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "output.check > 0",
      textInput(inputId = "field1", label = "First One", value = "")
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "output.check >= 2",
      textInput(inputId = "field2", label = "Second One", value = "")
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "output.check >= 3",
      textInput(inputId = "field3", label = "Third One", value = "")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$check <- reactive({
    length(input$numfields)
  })

  outputOptions(output, 'check', suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)    
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: This solution crashes with the error `Error in .subset2(x, "impl")$outputOptions(name, ...) : 
  check is not in list of output objects` is there possibly a package that is required that makes this work on your machine, but not mine?

Comment: i made an edit, i just made some refactoring that it looks nicer. But it seems that `outputOptions(output, 'check', suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)` has to come after the reactive function,...never noticed that. Learned smthg :).

Comment: There we go, now it works as intended and I am marking it as correct because the other answer populates all of the fields until one of the entries is selected, whereas your solution does displays a blank page until an option is selected.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a default selection in a `selectInput()` using the `selected =` argument:

```
selectInput(inputId = "numfields", 
            label = "Select Entries", 
            choices = Choices, 
            multiple = TRUE, 
            selectize = TRUE, 
            selected = 'A')
```

The `condition =` argument in the `conditionalPanel()` takes a literal that's interpreted as `JS` rather than `R`.

To check for the input 'count' you should use `input.numfields.length`:

```
conditionalPanel(
  condition = "input.numfields.length >= 1",
  textInput(inputId = "field1", label = "First One", value = "")
)
```

Below the complete `ui`:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    selectInput(inputId = "numfields", 
                label = "Select Entries", 
                choices = Choices, 
                multiple = TRUE, 
                selectize = TRUE, 
                selected = 'A'),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.numfields.length >= 1",
      textInput(inputId = "field1", label = "First One", value = "")
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.numfields.length >= 2",
      textInput(inputId = "field2", label = "Second One", value = "")
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.numfields.length >= 3",
      textInput(inputId = "field3", label = "Third One", value = "")
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: This works as intended, but instead of setting `selected = 'A'`, is there a way to set it so that it selects the first entry, which in this instance is A, without specifying to select A?  The reason I ask is that in my code this select input is reactive based on a different input and therefore, the first entry will be different depending on the input of a different field.

Comment: but if its reactive on different input, it should be wrapped within `renderUI()` anyway, no?