# Conditional panel based on a selectInput with emoji

Tags: r, shiny, selectinput

I have a `SelectInput` with text and emojis (using `install.packages("devtools")` , and then `devtools::install_github("hadley/emo")`).

I am trying to define a condition based on the choices:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(stringi)

ui <- fluidPage(

  mainPanel(
    
    div(selectInput(inputId = "MySelection",
                    label = "Which choice ? :",
                    choices = c(
                                paste("No selection",
                                        stri_dup(intToUtf8(160), 3),
                                        emo::ji("sun")),
                                "Selection one",
                                "Selection two"
                                ),
                    width = '350px'
    )
    ),
    width = 3 
  ),
  
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.MySelection.indexOf('No selection') > -1",
    "Test number 1"
  )
  
)


server <- function(input, output){
  output$ChoosenSection <- renderText({
    input$MySelection
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, the solution I found (with `indexOf() > -1`) is based on whether the choices contain some characters.

Instead, how can I ask for the exact value?
In order to say it in human language:

`condition = ‘ the choice is equal to :    paste("No selection", stri_dup(intToUtf8(160), 3), emo::ji("sun")) ‘`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional Panel based on number of user selected inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44418241/conditional-panel-based-on-number-of-user-selected-inputs)

Comment: Thank you for the proposition. No it doesn't answer, as I have already seen the general way (condition = "String of the selected choice"), but in my case, I cannot put the "" around paste("No selection",
                                        stri_dup(intToUtf8(160), 3),
                                        emo::ji("sun"))  .  It does not work.

Comment: perhaps use a named list for the `choices` to simplify things? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33105044/make-list-for-shiny-dropdown-selectinput

Comment: For the names list : it is close to another solution, which is to simply use names without list.
But here is the issue : 1) when I write ` "No_Selection" = paste("No selection", stri_dup(intToUtf8(160), 3), emo::ji("sun")) ` , then what is is displayed is "No_Selection". 2) But when I do it the other way around, then I got the following mistake : ` Error in sourceUTF8(fullpath, envir = new.env(parent = sharedEnv)) ` . And even if I add ` options(encoding = "UTF-8") ` at the beginning of the script, it's still wrong !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it works with a named list:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  mainPanel(
    
    div(selectInput(inputId = "MySelection",
                    label = "Which choice ? :",
                    choices = setNames(
                      1:3, 
                      c(
                        paste("No selection",
                              stri_dup(intToUtf8(160), 3),
                              emo::ji("sun")),
                        "Selection one",
                        "Selection two"
                      )),
                    width = '350px'
    )
    ),
    width = 3 
  ),
  
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.MySelection.indexOf('1') > -1",
    "Test number 1"
  )
  
)
```

Comment: Thank you ! Someone had provided the idea of a named list, but I did not manage to code it correctly. With you code, I got the answer. Amazing !